# 404 Error when trying to send data to backend port Golang

Tags: go, http-status-code-404

I am totally new in web dev and trying to make a simple CURD page, I finished migrating my Go code with MySQL database using sqlc, but I cannot push the data onto the route on local port that I want, it always returns `404 page not found` when I try to access /posts/ or anything similar. Can someone tell me where did I miss or gone wrong?

my models:

```
type Post struct {
    ID       int32  `json:"id"`
    PostID   string `json:"post_id"`
    Title    string `json:"title"`
    Content  string `json:"content"`
    Category string `json:"category"`
}
```

my Handler.go:

```
package posts 

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"

    db "my path to database"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
    //"github.com/go-chi/render"

)

type Handler struct {
    db *db.Queries
}

func NewHandler(db *db.Queries) *Handler {
    return &Handler{db: db}
}

func (h *Handler) HandleListPosts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()
    posts, err := h.db.ListPost(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, "Can't get")
        return
    }
    respondwithJSON(w, http.StatusOK, posts)
}

func (h *Handler) HandleGetPost(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()
    postID := chi.URLParam(r, "post_ID")
    post, err := h.db.GetPost(ctx, postID)
    if err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, "Can't get")
        return
    }
    respondwithJSON(w, http.StatusOK, post)
}

func respondwithJSON(w http.ResponseWriter, code int, payload interface{}) {
    response, _ := json.Marshal(payload)

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    w.Write(response)
}

func respondWithError(w http.ResponseWriter, code int, msg string) {
    respondwithJSON(w, code, map[string]string{"message": msg})
}
```

my routes:

```
func PostRouter(db *db.Queries) *chi.Mux {
    r := chi.NewRouter()

    h := NewHandler(db)

    r.Get("/", h.HandleListPosts)
    r.Get("/{post_id}", h.HandleGetPost)
    r.Post("/new", h.HandleCreatePost)
    r.Put("/{post_id}/edit", h.HandleUpdatePost)
    r.Delete("/{post_id}", h.HandleDeletePost)

    return r
}
...

func (s *Server) Reroute() *chi.Mux {
    r:= chi.NewRouter()
    r.Mount("/posts", PostRouter(s.db))
        return nil
    })

    return r
```

my main.go:

```
type Server struct {
    Version string
    db *db.Queries
    router *chi.Mux
    httpServer *http.Server
}

func New() *Server{
    s := &Server{
        Version: "1.0.0",
        router: router.SetupServer(),
    }

    return s
}

func (s *Server) RunServer() *Server{
    s.httpServer = &http.Server{
        Addr: ":4000",
        Handler: s.router,
    }

    f.Println("Server is running on port 4000")
    log.Fatal(s.httpServer.ListenAndServe())

    return s
}

// ...in router

func SetupServer() *chi.Mux {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Use(middleware.Logger)
    r.Use(middleware.Recoverer)
    r.Use(cors.Handler(cors.Options{
// Go Chi cors 
      }))

    r.Get("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        _, err := w.Write([]byte("Main page"))
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
    })

    return r
}
```

I tried with many ways to encode the data to JSON many times, it works ok with database methods but without use in Handler, and I don't know how to check if my Handler actually work. I am trying to send data from database to a localhost backend to send the data back to frotnend. Or am I actually missing how all of this actually works?

Comment: You never call Reroute.